# SSIS 2012 Executing with code

Tags: ssis

I wrote a SSIS 2012 package  in VS2012. I deployed on local sql server. I ran it on the server its working well.

I am trying to execute it threw WS or something similar. I am using LoadFromSqlServer and i keep on getting

"The specified package could not be loaded from the SQL Server database."

Is this authentication  or deployment problem.

thanks

Comment: Using the new project deployment model in 2012 or the classic/legacy package deployment model?

Comment: Hi. Using project Deployment model.

Answer (score 0):

I change to "IntegrationServices" classes and iterated threw catalog/project/package and executed it this way.

thanks